# Environment Variables in JS/Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there anyway I can get an environment variable (like an API key) to appear inside JS/Coffee using Rails 3.1?

Comment: The given answer is good, but you can also set a global JS variable from your view like (HAML): `:javascript \n
window.API_KEY = '#{ENV['API_KEY']}';`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can rename your file.js to file.js.erb and use ruby to access ENV:

```
<% do_something_with ENV['key'] %>
some_js_code
```

Comment: Should work if properly named. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets section 2.2.3