# Adding Google Analytics to Rails 4.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-analytics

I've got a Rails 4.2 app that I've deployed with Heroku and I've tried to add Google Analytics to it. However, Google Analytics isn't picking up any sessions.

Any suggestions why and how to resolve this?

**CODE**

/app/layouts/_footer.html.erb:

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'herokuapp.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
<% end %>
```

/app/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
<%= Gon::Base.render_data({}) %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
</div>

<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

</body>
</html>
```

/app/assets/javascripts/analytics.js.coffee:

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
 if window._gaq?
  _gaq.push ['_trackPageview']
 else if window.pageTracker?
  pageTracker._trackPageview()
```

/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require analytics
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require Chart
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require lodash
//= require_tree .
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'chart-js-rails'
gem 'gon'
gem 'lodash-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Just so you know, you're mixing two different versions of Google Analytics web tracking libraries in this question. In your `_footer.html.erb` you're using the [analytics.js tracking snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), but in your `analytics.js.coffee` file you're using the legacy ga.js code, which won't do anything because you never loaded the ga.js library, you loaded analytics.js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are adding your script is the wrong way, since it will not work due to Turbolinks, you know the code you have in your _footer won't be running as expected since that piece of markup won't reload because of Turbolinks.

I will give you my custom implementation of google analytics for all my rails apps.

In your app/assets/javascripts create a new file called google_analytics.js.coffee and add the following script:

```
class @GoogleAnalytics

  @load: ->
    # Google Analytics depends on a global _gaq array. window is the global scope.
    window._gaq = []
    window._gaq.push ["_setAccount", GoogleAnalytics.analyticsId()]

    # Create a script element and insert it in the DOM
    ga = document.createElement("script")
    ga.type = "text/javascript"
    ga.async = true
    ga.src = ((if "https:" is document.location.protocol then "https://ssl" else "http://www")) + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js"
    firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore ga, firstScript

    # If Turbolinks is supported, set up a callback to track pageviews on page:change.
    # If it isn't supported, just track the pageview now.
    if typeof Turbolinks isnt 'undefined' and Turbolinks.supported
      document.addEventListener "page:change", (->
        GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()
      ), true
    else
      GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()

  @trackPageview: (url) ->
    unless GoogleAnalytics.isLocalRequest()
      if url
        window._gaq.push ["_trackPageview", url]
      else
        window._gaq.push ["_trackPageview"]
      window._gaq.push ["_trackPageLoadTime"]

  @isLocalRequest: ->
    GoogleAnalytics.documentDomainIncludes "local"

  @documentDomainIncludes: (str) ->
    document.domain.indexOf(str) isnt -1

  @analyticsId: ->
    # your google analytics ID(s) here...
    'UA-xxxxxxxx-x'

GoogleAnalytics.load()
```

As you can see it adds support for Turbolinks, this is a clean and better way to add Google analytics to your app. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks. And in the `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:` file I should replace `//= require analytics` with `//= require analytics`?

Comment: you do not need to modify your application.js since you already have `//= require_tree .` you do not need `//= require analytics` at all...

Comment: @SsouLlesS Looks great! Is there a way to limit it to the production environment?

Comment: @slehmann36 well, you can access the current ENV and add conditionals in the script, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082465/environment-variables-in-js-coffeescript

Comment: is this .js.coffee file the only thing you need, or is it necessary to reference somewhere else?

Comment: @JuanseCora you just need to add the coffee files in your assets that's it, don't forget the thumbs up !!